# How to get (decode) resulting object from JSON

Tags: jquery, json, decode

I have used `JSON_encode()` to create a string from an array but I am stuck as to how I get the data once it has been encoded.  I am accessing the result via jQuery but I am lost with the formatting

**Result:**

```
froms: "[{"campaign_froms":"that"},{"campaign_froms":"why \r"},{"campaign_froms":"that\r"},{"campaign_froms":"this\r"}]"
subjects: "[{"campaign_subjects":"hi"},{"campaign_subjects":"hi\r"}]"
```

**jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      url: "campaignDetails.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(response){
          $('#offer_title').text(response["data"]["campaign_name"]);
          $('#offer_link').val(response["data"]["offer_link"]);
          $('#optout_link').val(response["data"]["optout_link"]);
          $('#campaign_image').val(response["data"]["campaign_image"]);
          $('#optout_image').val(response["data"]["optout_image"]);
          $('#subjects').val(response["subjects"]["campaign_subjects"]);
          $('#froms').val(response["froms"]["campaign_froms"]);
          $('#campaign_id').val(response["data"]["id"]);
          $('.campaignImageViewer').attr("src", imageUrl + response["data"]["campaign_image"]);
          $('.optoutImageViewer').attr("src", imageUrl + response["data"]["optout_image"]);
          //alert(response[0]["offer_link"]);
          console.log(response);
     }
});
```

Comment: Do all the other parts of the response have multiple key/value pairs?  Have you tried looping through `subjects` and `froms` and `appending` the values to the divs - rather than trying to insert an array?

Comment: show your sample json response.

Comment: @JessMcKenzie If my answer helps, please accept. If it doesn't, then some feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `jQuery.parseJSON()` function to decode it into a JS object.

So, change this line:

```
success: function(response) {
```

into:

```
success: function(data) {
    response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

This will get the result as `data`, and convert it into the JS object `response` that you use. And then your second block of code should work.

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Better now?

Comment: Gives me: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Did you change `function(response)` to `function(data)`?

Comment: Thanks but now I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Go back to your original code and try to change that one line again.

Comment: I have and I have success: function(data){
               response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  $('#offer_title' still the same issue

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cjzxbrf/): When clicking "JSHint" you can see that there is no error with these two lines.